# Allowing users to edit and move documents, but not delete them

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, event-handlers, delete, custom-permission-level

I have two questions here. The first question is that I need to allow users to add documents, edit them but not delete them. I know that this is possible somehow by writing a code using the ItemDeleting event handler. However I do not know what code would be required..

The second question is, obviously it seems that you can write codes to a SharePoint site. What I have not known is where I can write these codes? I have Visual Studio with the SharePoint extension installed. Where in the SharePoint online settings can I add or delete code?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write code to achieve this, just custom the permisson level in `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/user.aspx` to achieve this.

[image]

In the custom permissin level, make sure you uncheck the option "Delete Item". Like this：

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try that out. But I would still like to know where and how I can put codes into the sharepoint? Like if I want to code a rule for an eventhandler or anything at all?

Comment: You need to depoly the solution after creating the project. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver?view=vs-2019  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/developing-sharepoint-solutions?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom permission level based on default Contribute permission level in SharePoint.

In custom permission level, you can uncheck delete permissions from list.

Check below links for steps in details:

1. [SharePoint Online: How to Set Permissions to Add But Not Delete](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/02/sharepoint-online-permissions-to-add-but-not-delete.html)
2. [SharePoint online site permissions add but not delete](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-site-permissions-add-but-not/3a9d66d9-5228-4cf3-a3f2-f9df9443ff0f)